# Cypress failed to start on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, cypress

I have just installed Cypress using "npm install cypress --save-dev" and got confirmation that the install was successful as detailed below

- Downloaded Cypress
- Unzipped Cypress
- Finished installation

Tried opening Cypress using the prompt: node_modules.bin\cypress open but got the below message but there was no error listed. Has anyone come across this?

"It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 1.4.1

→ Cypress Version: 1.4.1
Cypress failed to start.

This is usually caused by a missing library or dependency.

The error below should indicate which dependency is missing.

https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies

### If you using Docker, we provide containers with all required dependencies installed.

---

Platform: win32 (10.0.14393)
Cypress Version: 1.4.1"

Comment: May be remove your node_modules and and reinstall the packages

Answer (score 45):

Try this  `npx cypress install --force` then use `npx cypress open`

Comment: Or `yarn run cypress install --force` with yarn.

Answer (score 34):

I've had the same issue. After running

```
npm install --save-dev cypress
```

you need to run

```
.\node_modules\.bin\cypress.cmd install
```

That's a bit confusing in most install guides that I read. After doing this, it worked for me.

Comment: `.\\node_modules\\.bin\\cypress.cmd install` in Bash

Comment: I had to run it with "--force" to force reinstall

Comment: Yes, for some reason the post-install script fails, or doesn't run at all when you install it a a devDep. So a force reinstall is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2657)

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=
cypress run
```

Answer (score 2):

Add below code of line in `package.json` file

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cypress open"
  }
}
```

and run cypress thro' editor command prompt using below command prompt

```
npm run test
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing a library or dependency, simply run: `npm install` to install all missing libraries and dependencies required in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you must have sorted out the issue.

If not, try to delete the cache and rerun cypress. It should work. If you use mac, run below command before running cypress open.

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Caches/Cypress/
```

Answer (score 0):

At the outset, I encountered the same issue when I initially attempted to install Cypress using 'npm'. Despite trying various methods, none proved successful in getting me started. However, upon retrying the installation using 'yarn' and opting for a direct download and installation of Cypress, I finally found success. Following the 'yarn' command, Cypress began running as expected, devoid of any errors. Presently, I can smoothly utilize 'npx cypress open' without any issues also.

Answer (score -1):

You may have already solved this, however, if not try downloading the binary from [download.cypress.io/desktop](https://download.cypress.io/desktop)

> **Direct download**
>
> If you’re not using Node.js or npm in your project or you just want to try Cypress out quickly, you can always download Cypress
>   directly from our CDN.
>
> The direct download will always grab the latest available version. Your platform will be detected automatically.
>
> Just manually unzip and double click. Cypress will run without needing to install any dependencies.

Ref: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress.html#Direct-download

Answer (score -1):

```
.\node_modules\.bin\cypress.cmd install --force
```

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Docker images : https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/docker.html#

System dependencies : https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Recording-Tests-in-CI

[image]

Comment: The OP has indicated the platform is Win32.